# ASP.NET MVC controller sends data to view but 'ThenInclude' data in view is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my controller I am using `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` to fill my object.

When I debug and view the properties of the servicePackage, I can see all of the data I expect to see is there:

```cs
ServicePackage servicePackage = await _context.ServicePackage
    .Include(bs => bs.ServicePackageLines)
    .ThenInclude(bsl => bsl.Product)
    .Where(bs => bs.Id == id)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

// viewing the properties of this servicePackage
// shows that there is product data when I drill down.
return View(servicePackage);
```

But in the view I cant access the data:

```cs
@model Domain.Entities.ServicePackage

@foreach (var lineDetail in Model.ServicePackageLines)
{
    @if(lineDetail.Product != null)
    { 
        <td>@lineDetail.Product.SupplierModelNumber</td> 
    }
    else
    {
        <td>@lineDetail.ProductId</td> 
    }
}
```

Always shows the line detail product Id, and not the model number.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but it would be great if someone could put me on the right path.

Comment: Have you confirmed that there is data that should be displayed?

Comment: yes, when I debug and view the properties of the servicePackage, I can see all of the data I expect to see [in the product object] is there.

Comment: Which version of Asp.net core version you are using? You could also set a break point the `@foreach` statement and check whether the data is existing or not. Besides, whether you are using `System.Text.Json` or `Newtonsoft.Json` to serialize and deserialize the JSON. Try to install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package via Nuget, then use it in your application : `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();`.